# Group row data from a 2d array by one column, remove one column, and populate a subarray from another column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, sub-array

I have an array with values like:

```
$menuArray = [
    [
        'parent' => 'Basic',
        'parentId' => 1,
        'child' => 'Birthday',
        'childId' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Basic',
        'parentId' => 1,
        'child' => 'Gender',
        'childId' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Geo',
        'parentId' => 10,
        'child' => 'Current City',
        'childId' => 11,
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Known me',
        'parentId' => 5,
        'child' => 'My personality',
        'childId' => 7,
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Known me',
        'parentId' => 5,
        'child' => 'Best life moment',
        'childId' => 8,
    ],
];
```

And I want to group this array on `parent` (or `parentId`) and the final result would be like:

```
[
    [
        'parent' => 'Basic',
        'parentId' => 1,
        'child' => ['Birthday', 'Gender'],
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Geo',
        'parentId' => 10,
        'child' => ['Current City'],
    ],
    [
        'parent' => 'Known me',
        'parentId' => 5,
        'child' => ['My personality', 'Best life moment'],
    ],
]
```

My current code:

```
$filter = [];
$f = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menuArray); $i++) {
    $c = 0;
    for ($b = 0; $b < count($filter); $b++) {
        if ($filter[$b]['parent'] == $menuArray[$i]['parent']) {
            $c++;
        }
    }
    if ($c == 0) {
        $filter[$f]['parent'] = $menuArray[$i]['parent'];
        $filter[$f]['parentId'] = $menuArray[$i]['parentId'];
        $filter[$f]['child'][] = $menuArray[$i]['child'];
        $f++;
    } 
}
```

But it doesn't push `child` values from subsequent encounters of a parent-related row into the result array.

Comment: Direct answer to your question is you're not adding children when you've found a matching parent already defined. As well as saying `c++` you should also say `filter[$b]['child'][] = $menuArray[$i]['child']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$filter = array();
foreach ($menuArray as $menu) {
  if (!array_key_exists($menu['parent_id'], $filter)) {
    $filter[$menu['parent_id']] = array(
      'parent' => $menu['parent'],
      'parent_id' => $menu['parent_id'],
      'child' => array()
    );
  }
  $filter[$menu['parent_id']]['child'][$menu['child_id']] = $menu['child'];
}
```

This will produce an array like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent] => Basic
            [parentId] => 1
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Birthday
                    [3] => Gender
                )

        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [parent] => Geo
            [parentId] => 10
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [11] => Current City                  
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [parent] => Known me
            [parentId] => 5
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [7] => My personality
                    [8] => Best life moment
                )

        )
)
```

Notice that the array indexes match the IDs. You can't loop this with a for loop but you can `foreach ($filter as $parent_id=>$parent)` correctly. If you want to you can change line 4 of my code to `$filter['key_' . $menu['parent_id']]` to force a string and a for loop will work

Answer (score 0):

The next piece of code is completely untested, and based on the idea that it's sorted by parentId.

```
$filter = array();
$option = null;
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $menuArray ); $i++ ) {
    if( count( $filter ) < 1 || $filter[count($filter)-1]['parentId'] != $menuArray['parentId'] ) {
        if( $option != null ) {
            $filter[]   = $option;
        }

        $option = array(
            "parent"    => $menuArray[$i]['parent'],
            "parentId"  => $menuArray[$i]['parentId'],
            "child"     => array()
        );
    }

    $option['child'][]  = $menuArray[$i]['child'];
}

$filter[]   = $option; // one last time, because we left the loop already.
unset( $option ); // we don't need it anymore.
```

What it does, it creates a `$option` for every parent. As soon as we hit the next `parentId` we add the current `$option` to the `$filter` array and create a new `$option` object.

All the children just keep getting added to the current `$option`.

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate the input array only once.
- If encountering a `parentId` for the first time, mutate the row by removing the `childId` elemement and cast the `child` value as an array -- which will convert the scalar value to a single-element array containing the value.

  Then push the mutated row into the result array as an associative multidimensional entry so that subsequent encounters of the `parentId` can be acknowledged.
- If encountering a `parentId` after the first time, merely push the `child` value into its respective group in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BBZ2N))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['parentId']])) {
        unset($row['childId']);
        $row['child'] = (array) $row['child'];
        $result[$row['parentId']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['parentId']]['child'][] = $row['child'];
    }
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

If you prefer to not mutate the (copied value of) `$row` with function calls, you can manually type out the desired structure. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hjkWv))

```
    // if (...) {
        $result[$row['parentId']] = [
            'parent' => $row['parent'],
            'parentId' => $row['parentId'],
            'child' => [$row['child']]
        ];
    // } else...
```